# Compile C code and simulate using gem5 SE

Tags: arm, scons, gem5

I am new to Gem5, I am trying to compile my C code and simulate it on an ARM like system using SE.

- First, to compile my C code, I used SCons (without any additional parameters). In the SConstruct file, I wrote:

> Program('hello.c')

- Second, to run the simulation, I am using:

> ./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/deprecated/example/se.py -c tests/test-progs/hello/bin/arm/linux/hello

Where hello is the output of my compilation, note that the size of this bin file is much smaller than the example bin files already found in Gem5. So I don't know if the problem is in the compilation or in the simulation.

Note that I am using the se.py in the deprecated directory because it was working with the hello_world example already found in Gem5 examples.

**The problem is that I am getting the following error, when using se.py:**

> 'No SE workload is compatible with %s'

While other sim Objects are not performing the simulation at all, or raising an assertion error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you set up SCons to use an arm compiler? Or are you just using your system gcc(x86/x64)?

Comment: The error you get is confusing - it looks like a substitutable element hasn't been substituted - we have no way of telling whether this is a problem with the way the error message is generated, or with the actual generated workload (see the `%s`). You might want to look into this...

Comment: Thank you for your help! 

Actually, no, I don't know the best practice to compile for ARM or which SimObj to use in Gem5 since I am getting a warning that se.py will be deprecated. 

Please, can you suggest a list of steps to follow in order to accomplish my goal?